# Logic which depends on the point of view / perspective? (Semantic space of logic)

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, hilbert-spaces, paradox

I am not sure if this question is appropriate for MO, since I have only a basic understanding of Boolean logic, and am maybe not qualified to ask questions beyond that, but still I will try to write what I have in mind:

In everyday logic, we emphasize the perspective / point of view of someone who is trying to convince someone else with "his logic".

I tried to take this literally to marry vectors in some Hilbert space with Luwaksiewiecz logic [in a short unpolished essay](https://archive.org/details/semantic_space_of_logic/page/n1/mode/2up) which raises more questions than it answers:

Let me rephrase the ideas there, here:

The ideas here are to first start with a set of things and a positive semidefinite kernel on these things. The theory of RKHS / Moore-Aaronszajn theorem, gives us a Hilbert space $H$ where miracously $k(x,y) = \left < \phi(x), \phi(y)\right>$ where $\phi: X \rightarrow H$ is an injective function, called 'feature mapping' in machine learning. Now suddenly we can do geometry on this set abstract set of things $X$. The conclusion of machine learning community is, that a 'feature vector' $\phi(x)$ of $x$ captures the 'semantic of the element $x$' relative to $k$.

Taking the perspective of everyday logic, we might want be able to give a semantic meaning to the phrase 'different point of views'.
But this is very easy done in geometry, since if $x$ takes the perspective of $w$, then we might want to project the unit vector $\phi(x)$ to the unit vector $\phi(w)$, to get:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:pi_w}
\pi_w(x) = \frac{k(w,x)}{|w|^2}w = k(w,x)w
\end{equation}

For this last equation, we write:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:relative_to_w}
x \text{ (relative to } w) := \pi_w(x) = k(w,x)w
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:length_x_w}
|x|_w := |\pi_w(x)|
\end{equation}

which is the length of the projected vector.

Now we can imagine what the meaning of 'I have a different perspective' means. We simply associate the projection of the semantic vector of $x$ to some other perspective vector $w$. Then 'changing perspective' simply means to change the perspective vector from $w$ to say $\hat{w}$.

Let us define

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:land_relative_to_w}
x \land y \text{ (relative to } w) := \min(k(w,x),k(w,y)) \phi(w)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:lor_relative_to_w}
x \lor y \text{ (relative to } w) := \max(k(w,x),k(w,y)) \phi(w)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:not_x}
\lnot x := - \pi_w(x)
\end{equation}

and following Lukasiewicz:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:implies_relative_to_w}
x \rightarrow y \text{ (relative to } w) := \min(1,1+|y|_w-|x|_w) w
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:equvi}
x \leftrightarrow y  \text{ (relative to } w) := x \equiv y := (x \rightarrow y) \land (y \rightarrow x)
\end{equation}

We have the de Morgan rules, double negation, contraposition:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:de_morgan_1}
(\lnot x) \land (\lnot y)  =  \lnot ( x \lor  y ) \text{ (relative to } w)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:de_morgan_2}
(\lnot x) \lor (\lnot y)  =  \lnot ( x \land  y ) \text{ (relative to } w)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:double_neg}
(\lnot (\lnot x)) = x \text{ (relative to  w)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:contraposition}
(x \rightarrow y ) = ((\lnot y) \rightarrow (\lnot x)) \text{ (relative to  w)}
\end{equation}

Let us define three cases of truth values: $T,F,I$ which should be translated to True, False, Indeterminate.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:truth}
\mu(x) =
\begin{cases}
    T & \text{if } k(w,x) < 0, \\
    I & \text{if } k(w,x) = 0, \\
    F & \text{if } k(w,x) > 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

We have a version of 'Modus ponens':

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:mp}
\text{ If } \mu(x)=T \text{ and } \mu( x \rightarrow y ) = T \text{ then } \mu( (x \land ( x \rightarrow y)) \rightarrow y) ) = T
\end{equation}

**Lukasiewicz logic and Liar paradoxon**
Let me give a concrete example:

$X:= \{-e_1,e_0,e_1\}$
where $e_1 = (1,0), e_0 = (0,1), -e_1 = (-1,0)$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual dot product.

Gram matrix:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:gramll}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Now we will loop with $w$ through all three different elements of $X$ to get different perspectives:

\begin{equation}
w =  \left(0,\,1\right)
\end{equation}

And

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Or
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Implies
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Iff
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Perspecitve change:
$$w =  \left(1,\,0\right)$$

And
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
Or
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
Implies
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Iff
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Perspecitve change:
$$w =  \left(-1,\,0\right)$$

And
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right)$$
Or

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right)$$

Implies
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Iff
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Interpretation:
If we associate $T:=e_1,F:=-e_1,I:=e_0, w = e_1$ then we get the following interpretation of the Liar paradox:
$$\lnot e_0 = e_0$$
This is a sentence which from our current perspective ($w = e_1$) contradicts itself.

Changing the perspective to $w = e_0$ we get:

$$ e_0 = T$$

but then the previous (from the perspective before) vectors $-e_1,e_1$ both get the value $I$ and are indeterminate.
They are equivalent in the sense defined above, although as vectors not equal.
So from this perspective the vectors $-e_1,e_1$ 'lose' their previous meaning of $T,F$ to become equivalent $I \equiv I$.

In conclusion we can say, that the Liar Paradox can be given a semantic which depends on the perspective, without losing some
formal symbolism of logic.

**I could not find something similar for reference in Google so I am asking here, if this point of view has been explored in the literature before?**

Thanks for your help!